# Query wont return data once inputs are double digits, PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like so...

```
$levLimit = $_GET['levLimit'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `level` < '$levLimit'";
```

This works fine when `levLimit` is equal to any number up to 9, as soon as I try it with 10 it returns nothing.

This doesn't give me any mysql or php errors neither, is there anything glaringly obvious?

Comment: what is the column's length and type? and how many records are there?

Comment: Its 'varchar' and 255

Comment: you need to either cast it or change its type to one that can perform math. I also edited my comment above, asking for how many records there are.

Comment: there's also 19 records

Comment: ok thanks. The former part of my 2nd comment seems to be what you need to do. MySQL can't do math on text, only integers.

Comment: welcome. Mind if I post an answer so we can close it?

Comment: I hope I don't have to give you the injection talk...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either cast it (bit of a pain) or change the column type to one that can perform math.

MySQL can't do math on text the way you're trying to query now, only integers.

**Caution**: Your code is open to SQL injection. Please use a prepared statement for this.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

You can also use `(int)` for the GET array's value:

```
$levLimit = (int)$_GET['levLimit'];
```

which won't require a prepared statement but it's always best that you do.

---

**Edit:**

> *"This doesn't give me any mysql or php errors neither."*

That is because you enclosed the variable in single quotes in the query which MySQL read that as a string and you say that the column's type is `VARCHAR`.

- Had you **not** used single quotes around the variable, it would have thrown an error.